# Contact Builder- Use Data as root

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I am trying to change remove a data extension as root and add another one. When I uncheck the box for the one I want to remove, it doesnt save. When I try to access it again, it remains checked.

On the other hand, when I attempt to make the desired DE root, I get this.
[image]

The "use as root" block is greyed out.

I will appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: I believe Root relationships have been superseded by Salesforce. You can't create new/ change existing. Whatever is already built will stay as is

Comment: Thanks. The issue is I am trying to get the email field to appear in the channel address order and believe this is the way to do it. Can you please advise on how to overcome this?

Comment: Why do you need that? Even that is superseded now

Comment: Thanks alot for this Maneesh. When you say superseded, can you point to documentation on this.  The reason I am trying to do this is that Journey Builder is failing  to send messages to contacts. When I review the history, it points to a error to bind data to data bound member

Comment: The error could be because of other reasons. There is a setting in journey builder itself where you can set which email address to use . You don't need to go to contact builder for that

Comment: I have set it to use the email address from the data extension but it still fails.  Would appreciate any assistance of resolving this

Comment: Is your contact already in all subscribers or some population ? it is it a brand new contact ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59104/discussion-between-data-kid-and-maneesh).